# Books on the applications of mathematical topics?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

So two questions. What is real analysis? or just analysis? What topics does that entail? If I get a book on analysis will it explain the topics I've listed in the second part of my question?
What are some books/texts that deal with applications of ODE, Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus? Seems like the textbooks I've received through university deal with plug and spit out questions, no real abstraction or application.

Comment: Real analysis is basically calculus with proofs.  Most intro to ODE, linear algebra, and multivariable calculus books have a lot material on applications, especially in the exercises.  Also, this question seems too broad.

Comment: Real Analysis provides the theoretical underpinning to calculus.  It is long on theory and short on application.  If learning the applications is your goal, I would not start here.  Real Analysis class is also boot camp for math majors in the basics of proof writing.  You really do need a teacher to talk you through this aspect of the course.